# Why does sbt assembly in Spark project fail with "Please add any Spark dependencies by supplying the sparkVersion and sparkComponents"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly, spark-cloudant

I work on a sbt-managed Spark project with `spark-cloudant` dependency. The code is [available on GitHub (on `spark-cloudant-compile-issue` branch)](https://github.com/snowch/demo_2710/tree/spark-cloudant-compile-issue/scala_streaming_predictor_with_cloudant).

I've added the following line to `build.sbt`:

```
"cloudant-labs" % "spark-cloudant" % "1.6.4-s_2.10" % "provided"
```

And so `build.sbt` looks as follows:

```
name := "Movie Rating"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sparkVersion =  "1.6.0"
  Seq(
     "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
     "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
     "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided",
     "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % sparkVersion % "provided",
     "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion % "provided",
     "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-log4j-appender" % "0.9.0.0",
     "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.9.0.0",
     "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.9.0.0",
     "cloudant-labs" % "spark-cloudant" % "1.6.4-s_2.10" % "provided"
    )
}

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org", "apache", "spark", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("scala", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("META-INF", "maven", "org.slf4j", xs @ _* ) => MergeStrategy.first
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}

unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory { base => base / "lib" }

assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
```

When I execute `sbt assembly` I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Please add any Spark dependencies by 
   supplying the sparkVersion and sparkComponents. Please remove: 
   org.apache.spark:spark-core:1.6.0:provided
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE** I still can't reproduce the issue, but think it does not really matter.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Please add any Spark dependencies by supplying the sparkVersion and sparkComponents.

In your case, your `build.sbt` misses a sbt resolver to find `spark-cloudant` dependency. You should add the following line to `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "spark-packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"
```

**PROTIP** I strongly recommend using `spark-shell` first and only when you're comfortable with the package switch to sbt (esp. if you're new to sbt and perhaps other libraries/dependencies too). It's too much to digest in one bite. Follow https://spark-packages.org/package/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant.

Answer (score 2):

Probably related: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/150

Can you try adding `spIgnoreProvided := true` to your `build.sbt`?

(This might not be the answer and I could have just posted a comment but I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: Why do you think `spIgnoreProvided := true` could have helped? What plugin(s) would that be used by?